# MySQL DATE_ADD for same field

Tags: mysql

Why can the date field `nextdate` not be updated by an interval by doing the following?

```
nextdate = DATE_ADD(`nextdate`, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: `set nextdate = DATE_ADD(nextdate, INTERVAL 30 DAY)`. Change single quotes to back ticks or remove them.

Comment: Or simply `set nextdate = nextdate + interval 30 day` should work. Dont forget to include where conditions.

Comment: @Ravinder that was unintentional, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove single quote on `nextdate` instead of single quote you have to use back ticks for field name

```
UPDATE table_name set `nextdate`= DATE_ADD(`nextdate`, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response but this did not work. Is this because we can not use same field in DATE_ADD and update it?

Comment: write your whole query which will you execute

Comment: It seems the issue was the date set to '0000-00-00' and that is why the trouble was, my bad. Now, works like a charm.